# No Space left on device after Jenkins installation

Tags: linux, centos, ruby, disk-space-utilization, io

Is there any reason i would get a 'No space left on device" error on `mkdir`.
I have confirmed that i have enough space left. around 68% is free. and also i have 1% iNodes consumed. This is CentOS 7 with SELinux disabled.

Following is the out of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      33540488 10571368  22969120  32% /
devtmpfs         3731924        0   3731924   0% /dev
tmpfs            3616424        0   3616424   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            3616424   254592   3361832   8% /run
tmpfs            3616424        0   3616424   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            2097152     2880   2094272   1% /tmp
```

And `df -i`:

```
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1     33550720 251008 33299712    1% /
devtmpfs         932981    296   932685    1% /dev
tmpfs            904106      1   904105    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            904106    426   903680    1% /run
tmpfs            904106     13   904093    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            904106     14   904092    1% /tmp
```

What else could cause this?

**edit**
Although this seems to arise when Jenkins runs a build which would install a newer version of ruby through rbenv and ruby-build.

Comment: Depending on how you install, the process might start by downloading and/or extracting archives to /tmp and that fills up more quickly than your root volume.

Comment: Don't disable SELinux.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes Definitely.  i'm just getting familiar with it first.

Answer (score 4):

maybe quota is enabled on the system. Check with

```
repquota -as
```

or

```
cat /etc/fstab | grep quota
```

(did not check if mkdir return No space left in case of quota)

Comment: repquota -as returns nothing.

Comment: cat /etc/fstab | grep quota return nothing as well.

Comment: try `lsof | grep deleted` maybe there is a large file deleted but still opened by a process. see [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671621/no-space-left-on-device)

Comment: `lsof | grep deleted` return empty

Answer (score -1):

To check the free space as ***Jenkins Job***:

## Parameters

- **`FREE_SPACE`**: Needed free space in *GB*.

## Job

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

free_space="$(df -Ph . | awk 'NR==2 {print $4}')"

if [[ "${free_space}" = *G* ]]; then
  free_space_gb=${x/[^0-9]*/}

  if [[ ${free_space_gb} -lt ${FREE_SPACE} ]]; then
    echo "Warning! Low space: ${free_space}"
    exit 2
  fi
else
  echo "Warning! Unknown: ${free_space}"
  exit 1
fi


echo "Free space: ${free_space}"
```

## Plugins

### Set build description

#### Post-Build Actions

- **Regular expression**: `Free space: (.*)`
- **Description**: `Free space: \1`
- **Regular expression for failed builds**: `Warning! (.*)`
- **Description for failed builds**: `\1`